# iphone where to go forward from learning cocos 2d by ray wenderlich

Tags: iphone

my question is about the ray wenderlich's book 
Learning Cocos2D: A Hands-On Guide to Building iOS Games with Cocos2D, Box2D, and Chipmunk

a very good book, now my question is that after studied it and implemented it, now when want to move forward for some more advanced game programing, what should be the way? means is there any other book or video tutorials links or any tutorials that can guide u from that stage for more advance work and expertise in iphone game programing...? plz. guide me thanx n Regards Saad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could purchase a cocos2d programming book:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1723

---

Or just search youtube of Cocos2d tutorials (preferably the more recent ones, but the older ones have some great info too!).

Comment: thanx Skullz, but before purchasing the book i again want to be confirmed that does that book takes you forward from where you ended after reading ray's book, means more advanced learning in cocos 2d game development? thanx for your guidance again.

Comment: Yes the book explains in great detail cocos2d and will help if you do ray's tutorials so you don't get confused